# Allow To Only Input A Number - C#

Tags: c#, console, numbers

I'm fairly new to C#.
I'm trying to make a basic program that converts Degrees in Celsius to Fahrenheit.
But here's the catch, I want to make sure that the user inputs only a valid number and no characters or symbols. And if the user inputs, for example 39a,23, the Console asks him to enter the number again.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Please enter the temperature in Celsius: ");
 double x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Also, I've been making other programs, and I've been wondering - do I always have to use "Convert.ToInt/Convert.ToDouble"? or is there a faster way?

Comment: Use RegularExpressionValidator with proper regular expression. you can easily find regular expression.

Answer (score 7):

It would be better you use the method `Double.TryParse`. This way you will check if the string that user provided can be parsed to a double.

```
// This is the variable, in which will be stored the temperature.
double temperature;

// Ask the  user input the temperature.
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the temperature in Celsius: ");

// If the given temperature hasn't the right format, 
// ask the user to input it again.
while(!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out temperature))
{
    Console.WriteLine("The temperature has not the right format, please enter again the temperature: ");
}
```

The method `Double.TryParse(inputString, out temperature)` will return `true` , if the parsing is successful and `false` if it isn't.

For more information about the method `Double.TryParse` please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. +1 from me for a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: Beat me to it, I'll delete my answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but, where do I exactly ask the user to input the number? in While () { } or outside of it? Somewhat confusing.

Comment: Oh, I see its - while (!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out temperature))

Comment: @TheQ oops. Thank you very much ! I just corrected it.

Comment: What does the "out" do anyway?

Comment: @TheQ as it stated in MSDN The out keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference. This is like the ref keyword, except that ref requires that the variable be initialized before it is passed. To use an out parameter, both the method definition and the calling method must explicitly use the out keyword

Comment: @TheQ So you pass by reference the variable `temperature` in the method called `Double.TryParse`. So inside the method's body, if the parsing succeed, before it will return `true`, it will assign the corresponding value to the variable `temperature` and this value will be visible outside the scope of this method, since you have passed this value by reference.